# Functions for returned values from ajax?

Tags: jquery

Basically, I tried to code the following. (note that I am a newbie in jQuery, trying to learn.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
    img.box:hover { opacity: 0.4; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(".box").click(function(event){
      $.post("./itemdrop.php", { id: "Item:1" }, function(data){
            $('#box').append(data);
         }
      );
  });

  $("li").click(function(event){
     $(".box").append("clicked");

  })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="box">
    <img class="box" src="./img/box.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It should work like this:

1. User clicks on "box" image, jQuery gets values from itemdrop.php

**The returned value is `<li class="item">Shield of Walmar</li>`**

However, the jQuery doesn't act when I click on Shield of Walmar. (I somehow have a feeling that the document ready function at top causes it.)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use live events/delegates. Since you are using a recent jQuery version, you want to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for it:

```
$('#box').on('click', 'li', function(event){
     $("#box").append("clicked");
});
```

I'd also suggest you to replace `jQuery(document).ready(function()` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` - otherwise `$` inside that function only works if it's available globally (i.e. `$.noConflict` wasn't used).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#box").on('click', 'li', function(event){
   $(".box").append("clicked");
})
```

**Quoting Docs:**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements **that are added to the document at a later time**. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.